# User can't checked input, when jQuery do it? Or something like that

Tags: jquery, html, input, checked

I have problem with jQuery script and checked input. I have such window in HTML:

[image]

And as you can see is there one checked input. When I try click on this input (not on text near it, just only on input) then script are run correctly, but input is not checked.

I wrote script to run when you click div, which is the input and text.

Here is a piece of code:

```
    $('#S8l2560g').find('input').css('cursor', 'pointer').parent().css('cursor', 'pointer').toggle(function() {
    //setCookie('Search information','hidden',168);
    $('#k5ORgvNM span').text('yes, is checked').css('color', 'red');
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
}, function() {
    //setCookie('Search information','visible',168);
    $('#k5ORgvNM span').text('no, is nonchecked').css('color', 'blue');
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
});
```

I do not know why this is happening. I suspect that this is a problem in HTML.

I cut this entire panel, and pasted it into jsFiddle, so you can check it out.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/sv7w5/

Just try to click only on input, and after on text near input.

I even tried to copy the toggle and move it before parrent, but it did not work.

It is not a big problem, because the script works, but it misleads people, making too many times to click.

[image]

Can I ask for help? I would like to make it work the way I want it.

Comment: That does not work for me.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<label>`

Comment: You are listening events to input parent `div` element not the input field. thats why its not getting check!

Comment: how use this <label>? btw. I forgot to add: I tested prof() and not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Musa use `<label />` instead of `<span />`

`<label />` has `for` attribute to target specific input field. So clicking on the label will focus the input element.

**Note:** The input `<input id="label-check" />` id value must be same as label `<label for="label-check">` for value.

HTML:

```
<label for="label-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="label-check" style="vertical-align: middle;"/> Nie pytaj więcej...
</label>
```

JS:

```
$('#S8l2560g').find('input').css('cursor', 'pointer').change(function(e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#k5ORgvNM span').text('yes, is checked').css('color', 'red');
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#k5ORgvNM span').text('no, is nonchecked').css('color', 'blue');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sv7w5/7/)

Comment: No also with `toggle` event and `parent()` method before the `toggle` event.

Comment: what is function(e) in change()?

Comment: Hmm it's work, but I changed only toggle() to change() and add this if ($(this).is(':checked')). The rest of the code isn't I changed, because already works. Ahh and I'm add <label>.

Comment: @IdolwSzutrab you can remove it simply `(e)`.

Comment: No remove the `parent()` method before the `toggle` event it is actually listening event to the `input` parent (`div`) but not the input it self.

Comment: There are thousands of ways to make it work. I tried my best to make code shorter and simple.